# Como llamar a this.state en un array

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-hooks

**Problema:** Tengo un array de componentes, la cosa es que tengo otro componente aparte que es un modal y quiero pasarle los datos del state de las componentes de mi array el problema entonces es que si fuese de manera individual es fácil llamar al state pero como puedo llamar a mi state si en este caso es un array de componentes lo que tengo

## State hook

```
state = {
    loading: true,
    Noticias: [],
    showModal: false
};
handleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
        showModal: !this.state.showModal
    });
}
```

## Render del array

```
    const noticiasJSX=[];
                this.state.Noticias.forEach(noticia => {
                    noticiasJSX.push( 
//Aquí quiero poder realizar { this.state.showModal? <div onClick={this.hanldeModal()} className="back-drop"></div> : null }
                        <div className="ml-3">
                            <div className="car-container">
                                <figure>
                                    <p>
                                        <img alt={noticia.foto} height="150px" width="300px" src={noticia.Foto}/>
                                    </p>
                                </figure>
                                <div>
                                    <div className="container">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>{noticia.Titulo}</strong>
                                            <br/>
                                            <small><i>Equipo: {noticia.Equipo}</i></small>
                                            <br/>
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="">Leer más</button>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    );
                });
                return(
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            {noticiasJSX}
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                );
```

Comment: ¿Tienes permitido modificar la estructura del objeto `Noticias[object]`? Cada objeto/elemento de `Noticias` tiene parámetros como `titulo`, `equipo` etc. ¿Se cuenta con un parámetro `id` o `noticia_id`? Saludos

Comment: @g.4 Cuentan con parámetros como bien dices y un id, pero a lo que refieres es a modificar los datos de la API directamente?

Comment: .@Estiwer,  se podría crear una copia de `Noticias`(es lo que trae la API supongo) y trabajar con la misma, declarándola como parte del `state`, a esta copia se le agrega la propiedad `showModal` para cada elemento. De esta forma se podría implementar el código que propones. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer no hay operaciones de escritura involucradas en la pieza de código, solo hay operaciones de lectura.

Se puede crear una copia del estado `Noticias` (es lo que trae la API supongo) y trabajar con la misma, declarando esta copia como parte del `state`:

```
this.state = {
      Noticias: [],
      NoticiasCustom: []
}
```

Luego, a esta copia `NoticiasCustom`  se le agrega la propiedad `showModal` para cada elemento:

```
 //ReactJS:creo una copia de Noticias
 const NoticiasCopy = [...this.state.Noticias];
 //ReactJs:agrego una nueva propiedad showModal a cada elemento
 NoticiasCopy.forEach((element, index) => element.showModal=true);
 //ReactJS:actualizo el estado NoticiasCustom
 this.setState({NoticiasCustom: NoticiasCopy})
```

La parte más complicada, cuando el usuario da click en el `div` `showModal`, aquí se hace una operación con el operador `elipsis` y el método [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), el objetivo es modificar la propiedad `showModal` del objeto `Noticias[n]` al que el usuario haya dado click y además, ensamblar nuevamente `NoticiasCustom`:

```
//[ ...regresa y propaga de 0 hasta noticia_id,
//{...inserta objeto[noticia_id] con propiedad showModal actualizada},
//...regresa y propaga de noticia_id +1 en adelante]
let newStateCopy = [
   ...this.state.NoticiasCustom.slice(0,noticia_id),
   {...objCopy,showModal: false},
   ...this.state.NoticiasCustom.slice(noticia_id+1)
]
```

Enseguida, se devuelve el componente con la actualización del `state.NoticiasCustom`:

```
this.setState({
   NoticiasCustom: newStateCopy
});
```

De esta forma se podría implementar el código que propones:

```
{ this.state.showModal ? <div onClick={this.hanldeModal}>Click me</div> : null }
```

Nótese que `showModal` ya es una propiedad de cada elemento del state `NoticiasCustom`, puede usarse en conjunto con el operador ternario y así, devolver su estado para cada elemento dentro del ciclo `forEach`:

```
{ noticia.showModal ? <div onClick={()=>this.hanldeModal(noticia.Id)}>Click me</div> : null }
```

A continuación un demo, con la implementación del código que se propone, para cada elemento en el arreglo `noticiasJSX`:

```js
let dataAPI = [
  {
    Id:0,
    Titulo:'titulo 1',
    Equipo:'equipo uno'
  },
  {
    Id:1,
    Titulo:'titulo 2',
    Equipo:'equipo dos'
  },
  {
    Id:2,
    Titulo:'titulo 3',
    Equipo:'equipo tres'
  },
  {
    Id:3,
    Titulo:'titulo 4',
    Equipo:'equipo cuatro'
  },
  {
    Id:4,
    Titulo:'titulo 5',
    Equipo:'equipo cinco'
  }
];

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      Noticias: [],
      NoticiasCustom: []
    }
    this.hanldeModal = this.hanldeModal.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    //API call
    this.setState({Noticias: dataAPI})
    
  }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
     if(prevState.Noticias.length !== this.state.Noticias.length){
      const NoticiasCopy = [...this.state.Noticias];
      NoticiasCopy.forEach((element, index) => element.showModal=true);
      this.setState({NoticiasCustom: NoticiasCopy})
     }
   }

  hanldeModal = (noticia_id) => {
    let objCopy = {...this.state.NoticiasCustom[noticia_id]};
    //
    //[ ...regresa y propaga de 0 hasta noticia_id
    //{...inserta objeto[noticia_id] con propiedad showModal actualizada}
    //...regresa y propaga de noticia_id +1 en adelante
    let newStateCopy = [
      ...this.state.NoticiasCustom.slice(0,noticia_id),
      {...objCopy,showModal: false},
      ...this.state.NoticiasCustom.slice(noticia_id+1)
    ];
    
    this.setState({
      NoticiasCustom: newStateCopy
    });
  }
  render(){
  const noticiasJSX = [];
   this.state.NoticiasCustom.forEach((noticia) => {     
    noticiasJSX.push(<div key={noticia.Id}>
      { noticia.showModal ? <div onClick={()=>this.hanldeModal(noticia.Id)}>Modal click</div> : null }
      <ul>
          <li>{noticia.Titulo},{noticia.Equipo}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>)    
   });
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {noticiasJSX}
            </div>                    
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

#### Notas de campo

- Se trato de emular la situación, si crees que es de utilidad, tendràs que implementar la demo con los cambios correspondientes de tu lado.
- Se esta usando el parametro `id` para cada noticia dentro del ciclo `forEach`, pues como mencionaste en los comentarios, si esta disponible.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.